# A consequence of the Selection Theorem for the Effros Borel space F(X) - self study

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, borel-sets, measurable-functions, measurable-sets, polish-spaces

In Kechris' textbook "Classical Descriptive Set Theory", the following exercise is stated (pp. $77$, Exercise $(12.14)$):

"Let X be a measurable space and Y a Polish space.
Show that a function $f\colon X \to F(Y)$ is measurable iff $f^{-1}(\{\emptyset\})$ is measurable and there is a sequence of measurable functions $f_n\colon X\to Y$ such that $\{f_n(x)\}$ is a dense subset of $f(x)$ when $f(x)\ne \emptyset$."

I'm able to prove $(\Rightarrow)$ as an immediate consequence of the Selection Theorem for $F(X)$, but I don't get the right idea to prove the converse $(\Leftarrow)$.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer! It is _also_ possible to upvote ;-) if it was satisfactory.

Comment: I've tryed, but "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score." I'm trying to fully understand your suggestion. If I need I'll ask you some other explanation and I'll upvote when possible :-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I wasn't fully aware of that rep limitation. Comment any doubts on the answer, perhaps some editing to clarify things might be needed.

Comment: I've understood your very plain proof, but looking at that I feel something is not clear to me. In order fill this gap, I would like to ask for your help to understand a previous example in Kechris' book (pp. $70$, Ex: $2$). Can I ask it in a comment or should I edit another question?

Comment: I know that example. What are your doubts? If I can answer in one line or two it wouldn't worth the effort of writing another question. (Nevertheless, posting a question might serve someone else.)

Comment: I would like to understand if I'm missing something about analysis or not: i don't understand why that characterization of $C^1$ functions holds and why the sets $A_{J, \epsilon}$ are cloed

Comment: The characterization is a translation of the fact that both the $\Delta f/\Delta x$ tend to $0$ and that $f'$ is continuous; explaining this in length could be a little tiresome (at least for me). That $A_{J,\epsilon}$ are closed is simpler: The universal quantifiers can be moved outside the set as intersections, and the remaining part follows from the fact that evaluation $a\mapsto f(a)$ is continuous.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience! About the 1st question I have to use the fact that $f′$ is uniformly continuous on $[0,1]$ and the definition of derivative, right? About the 2nd one I was right and I'm happy :) Thank you once again;  as I said before, I'll upvote your answer :)

Comment: That's right. You are welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is enough to show that the preimages of generators of the measurable space $F(Y)$ are Borel in $X$. Namely, for every open set $U\subseteq Y$, we need to check that 
$$
Q:=f^{-1}(\{F\in F(Y) : F\cap U \neq \emptyset\}) = \{x\in X : f(x)\cap U \neq \emptyset\}
$$ 
is Borel in $X$. Then we have
$$
f(x)\cap U \neq \emptyset \iff f(x) \neq \emptyset \land  \exists n . f_n(x)\in U,
$$
hence $Q = (X\setminus f^{-1}(\{\emptyset\})) \cap \bigcup_n f_n^{-1}(U)$, which is measurable since the $f_n$ are.